# Closing opened files

Tags: file, python-3.x, fclose

This code works but I want to close opened files. How to change this code ?

```
with open(output_file, "w", newline='') as f_output:
    try:
        os.remove(output_file)                                                          # Delete old file
    except OSError:
        pass
    for r in range(len(new_list)):
        open(output_file, "a").writelines(str(second_list[r] + '\n'))
```

Comment: Why you are trying to remove the `output_file` and then you are opening the file in append mode?

Comment: If old file exists - delete it, write new file and append new line in file. Else, write file and append new file in file.

Comment: Why you don't use `with` statement again? Also you better to move your `for` loop out of `with`.

Comment: Can you show me a example how should this looks ?

Answer (score 0):

The file closes automatically.

If you want to close the file then please change it to
(I left it as output_file because it looks like a variable)
    f_output = open(output_file, "w")

then you can just say f_output.close() when you want to close the file.